# Oracle expdp CentOS 6.2 Shell script unusual behavior - New line gives command not found

Tags: bash, centos, oracle11gr2, rhel5

My first post be gentle.

I have the script below which was taken out of a RedHat 5.3 box to backup an Oracle database. The script was working fine on the Redhat 5.3 box.  I then used it as a reference to backup an oracle db on a centos 6.2 box and modified it as required.

```
#!/bin/bash
ORACLE_HOME="/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1"
NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AR8ISO8859P6

BKDATE=`date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"`
C1="system/password@dbname DIRECTORY=RMBACKUP SCHEMAS=USER1,USER2,USER3 DUMPFILE=dbname_"
C2="_full_pump.dmp LOGFILE=dbname_"
C3="_full_pump.log"
BKCMD=$C1$BKDATE$C2$BKDATE$C3
echo $C1
echo $C2
echo $C3
echo $BKDATE
echo $BKCMD
#run the exp backup
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/expdp $BKCMD
```

The weird bahavior is that when I execute the script the new line causes a command not found error and the concatenation gets merged as seen below.

```
system/password@dbname DIRECTORY=RMBACKUP SCHEMAS=USER1,USER2,USER3 DUMPFILE=dbname_
_full_pump.dmp LOGFILE=dbname_
_full_pump.log
2012-07-10_09-39-06
system/password@dbname DIRECTORY=RMBACKUP SCHEMAS=USER1,USER2,USER3 DUMPFI_full_pump.log39-06ILE=dbname_
/bin/expdp: No such file or directoryacle/product/11.2.0/db_1
```

The date merging with the other text is not a typo, that is the echo output.

I added set -x at the beginning and here is the output

```
+ ORACLE_HOME=$'/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1\r'
+ NLS_LANG=$'AMERICAN_AMERICA.AR8ISO8859P6\r'
++ date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S
+ BKDATE=$'2012-07-10_10-27-45\r'
+ C1='system/password@dbname DIRECTORY=RMBACKUP SCHEMAS=USER1,USER2,USER3 DUMPFI'E=dbname_
' C2='_full_pump.dmp LOGFILE=dbname_
+ C3=_full_pump.log
+ BKCMD='system/password@dbname DIRECTORY=RMBACKUP SCHEMAS=USER1,USER2,USER3 DUM_full_pump.log'7-45ILE=dbname_
+ echo system/password@dbname DIRECTORY=RMBACKUP SCHEMAS=USER1,USER2,USER3 $'DUMPFILE=dbname_\r'
system/password@dbname DIRECTORY=RMBACKUP SCHEMAS=USER1,USER2,USER3 DUMPFILE=dbname_
+ echo _full_pump.dmp $'LOGFILE=dbname_\r'
_full_pump.dmp LOGFILE=dbname_
+ echo $'_full_pump.log\r'
_full_pump.log
+ echo $'2012-07-10_10-27-45\r\r'
2012-07-10_10-27-45
+ echo system/password@dbname DIRECTORY=RMBACKUP SCHEMAS=USER1,USER2,USER3 $'DUMPFILE=dbname_\r2012-07-10_10-27-45\r_full_pump.dmp' $'LOGFILE=dbname_\r2012-07-10_10-27-45\r_full_pump.log\r'
system/password@dbname DIRECTORY=RMBACKUP SCHEMAS=USER1,USER2,USER3 DUMPFILE=dbn_full_pump.log27-45ILE=dbname_
+ $'/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1\r/bin/expdp' system/password@dbname DIRECTORY=RMBACKUP SCHEMAS=USER1,USER2,USER3 $'DUMPFILE=dbname_\r2012-07-10_10-27-45\r_full_pump.dmp' $'LOGFILE=dbname_\r2012-07-10_10-27-45\r_full_pump.log\r'
/bin/expdp: No such file or directoryacle/product/11.2.0/db_1
```

Waiting for responses...

Comment: That's really strange. Can you redirect stdout of the script to the file and check this file?

Comment: And can you please add `set -x` to the beginning of the script to see what really happens during its execution?

Comment: Thank you for the response I added "set -x", see edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, there are `'\r'` characters in the texts. Probably you edited the file with an editor that adds `\r` at the end of lines automatically. You must edit the file once again and remove these characters.